# Creating an always evolving **number** of structs[x] using x

Tags: c, struct

I don't know how to phrase the title better but I want to parse a file and depending on the number of x's returned, create x amount of similar structs that I will later fill individually with different values!

So if `nb_structs` is the number of structs I need to create, how would I create them?

This is the struct that has to be duplicated:

```
typedef struct graph {
    int id;
    int ant;
    int box;
    int *rooms;
}graph_t;
```

It won't let me just put

```
typedef struct graph[nb_structs]
```

and I don't know how to put it in a header file since `nb_structs` is determined in  a function in my program!

(Also, my school won't let me use any other variables aside malloc, free, read and write for this project)

Comment: `malloc` is the correct solution; this is exactly what it's for.  Do you know how to work with `malloc` and dynamic allocation in general?

Comment: `malloc` is the general solution (see Sergey's answer). But, there is a VLA (variable length array) syntax. It goes in a function scoped declaration (_not_ the `typedef`): `void myfunc(void) { int nb_structs = ...; graph_t graphs[nb_structs]; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

It's usually done like this:

```
int nb_structs=2;
graph_t* graphs = malloc(nb_structs * sizeof *graphs);
for (x = 0; x < nb_structs; x++)
{
   graphs[x].id = 123;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I would also check the return value for null. Should be `sizeof *graphs`.